# Why is the ten commandments sometimes called the decalogue?

Tags: ten-commandments

I have heard the ten commandments written in Exodus and Deuteronomy sometimes called the Decalogue. What does this word mean and why are they sometimes called that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The English phrase "Ten Commandments" is a bit of a misnomer. The Hebrew phrase עֲשֶׂרֶת הַדְּבָרִים (*eseret ha-dvarim*) literally translates into English as "the ten words" or "the ten statements." The Hebrew phrase is translated into the LXX as δέκα λόγους (*deka logous*). Of course, from thence is derived the English expression "dekalogue" --- which is nothing more than a loose transliteration of that Greek phrase. δέκα λόγους is actually in the accusative case. The nominative would be δέκα λόγοι (*deka logoi*).

Answer (score 2):

Decalogue comes from 'dekalogos', where 'deka' means 'ten', and 'logos', which is 'word', or in this context, 'statements'.